# can i call a vector from a method within a class

Tags: java, class, vector, methods

[image]

```
abstract class Person
{
    String name;
    int age;
}
class Employee extends Person
{
    String subordinate_id;
    String department;
    int rank;

    public Employee(String name, int age, String subordinate_id, String department, int rank)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.subordinate_id = subordinate_id;
        this.department = department;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("I am a Employee");
        System.out.printf("My name is %s,I am %d years old.\n",name, age);
        System.out.printf("I am a %d level Employee.My employeeNumber is %s.I am working in %s\n",rank, subordinate_id, department);
    }
}
class Manager extends Employee
{
    Vector subordinate =  new Vector<Object>();

    public Manager(String name, int age, String subordinate_id, String department, int rank)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.subordinate_id = subordinate_id;
        this.department = department;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("I am a Employee");
        System.out.printf("My name is %s,I am %d years old.",name, age);
        System.out.printf("I am a %d level Employee.My employeeNumber is %s.I am working in %s",rank, subordinate_id, department);
        System.out.println("My subordinate has:");
    }
}
//the main was given to me in the question to solve for the rest of the code
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("zhangsan", 20, "s101", "d01", 3);
        e1.print();
        System.out.println();

        Employee e2 = new Employee("lisi", 20, "s202", "d02", 4);
        e2.print();
        System.out.println();

        e2 = new Employee("maliu", 20, "s102", "d01", 5);
        e2.print();

        Manager m1 = new Manager("wangwu", 30, "s100", "d01", 9);

        m1.getSubordinates().addElement(e1);
        m1.getSubordinates().addElement(e2);
        m1.print();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> I was given a main method and was asked to come up with the rest of the code there are three classes class Person class Employee and class Manager.the class Manager has a vector type subordinate according to the question.....i failed to understand getsubordinate().addElement(); in the main what does this line mean?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that this is very poor quality code (lack of private access level modifiers, new Vector() etc).

Back to the code:

1) You are missing getter (getSubordinate()) for Vector subordinate =  new Vector();

2) I believe it should be Vector subordinate = new Vector()

3) I would also consider using any list implementation instead of vector

4) After you add mentioned getter to the Manager class, this line m1.getSubordinates().addElement(e2) simply adds Employee to the vector object.